# Sparse columns in pandas: directly access the indices of non-null values

Tags: pandas, sparse-matrix, indices

I have a large dataframe (approx. 10^8 rows) with some sparse columns. I would like to be able to *quickly* access the non-null values in a given column, i.e. the values that are actually saved in the array. This could be achieved by `df.<column name>[<indices of non-null values>]`, but I can't see how to access `<indices of non-null values>` directly, i.e. without any computation. When I try `df.<column name>.index` it tells me that it's a `RangeIndex`, which doesn't help. I can even *see* `<indices of non-null values>` when I run `df.<column name>.values`, but looking through `dir(df.<column name>.values)` I still can't see a way to access them.

To make clear what I mean, here is a toy example:

[image: A sparse column]

In this example `<indices of non-null values>` is `[0,1,3]`.

EDIT: The answer below by @Piotr Żak is a viable solution, but it requires computation. Is there a way to access `<indices of non-null values>` directly via an attribute of the column or array?

Comment: `df[df['sparce_col'].notna()].index`

Comment: Yes, that would do it, but it requires computation. I would like to access the indices from the column directly. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1], [np.nan], [4], [np.nan], [9]]),
                   columns=['a'])
```

[image]

just filter without nan:

```
filtered_df = df[df['a'].notnull()]
```

[image]

transform column from df to array:

```
s_array = filtered_df[["a"]].to_numpy()
```

or - transform indexes from df to array:

```
filtered_df.index.tolist()
```

[image]

Comment: @dwolfeu - do You have maybe the comparison between times?

Comment: In the real example that I'm working on, where the dataframe has lots of columns, ```df.sparse_col[df.sparse_col.notnull()].index``` takes just under 2 seconds to run, while ```df[df.sparse_col.notnull()].index``` takes over 30 seconds.